# PyQT force update textEdit before calling other function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My question concerns PyQT5. 
I try to have a dialog window with a button that when clicked

1. updates some text of a `QTextEdit` field
2. calls a function (which needs much time to terminate)

Something like this:

```
class StartDialog(QtWidgets.QWidget, start_dialog_ui.Ui_Dialog):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.OKButton.clicked.connect(self.start)

 def start(self):
    self.startDialogTextEdit.append("simulation running ...")
    run_lengthy_function(self)
```

However, when I run my GUI I notice that the text is updated only *after* the lengthy function has terminated, although the `QTextEdit.append` is called before the lengthy function. How can I enforce that the text is updated in advance?

What I tried so far (but didn't work) was to let Python wait some time before triggering the lengthy function call, i.e.

```
from time import sleep

class StartDialog(QtWidgets.QWidget, start_dialog_ui.Ui_Dialog):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.OKButton.clicked.connect(self.start)

 def start(self):
    self.startDialogTextEdit.append("simulation running ...")
    sleep(5)
    run_lengthy_function(self)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The repaint is called in event loop so sleep the whole thread does not change anything.

You can call repaint manually by:

```
self.startDialogTextEdit.repaint()
```

or call static method:

```
QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

which also call repaint internally

Comment: Thanks a lot, `self.startDialogTextEdit.repaint()` works as desired.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for the case that the text is displayed in the `QTextEdit` is to call `qApp.processEvents()`, this force to the GUI update:

```
def start(self):
    self.startDialogTextEdit.append("simulation running ...")
    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
    [...]
```

On the other hand if the task is heavy it may be blocking the GUI, so maybe one solution is to run it on another thread, I can not give a proper recommendation since I do not know your function

Comment: Thanks, `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()` works for me as well. Also thanks for the hint to use another thread.