# PyQT force rendering some widget before calling other function

Tags: python, pyqt

I am designing a GUI for a Python project that manages some simulations. As the simulations take some time, I want to have a window that tells the user to wait, popping up when the simulation is started.

Currently, the code is like

```
def start_simulation(self):
    self.calculation_running_dialog.show()
    heavy_function_call(self)
    self.calculation_running_dialog.hide()
```

However, I face the following problem: **When the simulation is started the window does appear, but it is rendered with a transparent body in Ubuntu and with an empty (white) body in Windows.** Only after the heavy function call has terminated, the window is rendered properly. **How can I force the window to be displayed properly before the simulation starts?**

Recently, I have asked a similar question here: [PyQT force update textEdit before calling other function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654327/pyqt-force-update-textedit-before-calling-other-function).
For that purpose, the `repaint()` function turned out to be the solution. But for the current problem, neither `self.calculation_running_dialog.repaint()` nor `self.calculation_running_dialog.update()` or `self.calculation_running_dialog.textLabel.repaint()` does the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes it depends on the type of "heavy" function call.
If it depends on external events (such as network response, etc), usually a QTimer.singleShot with timeout 0 calling the function can suffice.
But if it asks too much resources to the program/cpu, it is better to create another QThread and do the heavy work there.

Comment: @musicamente Using another QThread works. Thanks for the hint!