# Python lines within method execute out of order

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is my first python project, decided to go hard with GUI stuff right off the bat. Please forgive me if my terminology is way off, I'm still learning.

I have the class `Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)` and within that, the method `__init__(self)`. Within that method, I define everything else, like objects, method/function calls, etc. It's worked for me so far according to a [tutorial I found](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-import-a-pyqt5-ui-file-in-a-python-gui/) detailing how to import and work with the PyQT .ui file directly instead of converting it with pyuic5 every time I make a change to the UI.

However, within one of my methods I set a couple variables, then append text to a Qt Widget with `self.plainText.appendPlainText("text goes here")` (I think this is called an instance attribute?), create a dir with `os.makedirs()`, append some more text, then make a call to another method containing a call to `subprocess.run()`, in that exact order.

Everything within this method gets executed as it should, but not in the order they were written, as the `appendPlainText` calls get executed *after* everything else is done executing, even after the call to `self.makerars()`.

Here is mockgui.ui:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>336</width>
    <height>362</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>25</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>65</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="buildPlainTextEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>145</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>166</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>336</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionBuild"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionBuild">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Build</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Below is the python file:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from time import sleep

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mockgui.ui', self)
        
        self.apps = "./Apps"
        self.rarexe = self.apps + "/rar/Rar.exe"

        # Declare objects from UI file as self objects
        self.actionBuild = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, "actionBuild")
        self.InputEdit = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'lineEdit') # Input folder
        self.OutputEdit = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'lineEdit_2') # Output base folder
        self.TitleEdit = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'lineEdit_3') # Final name and folder of archive
        
        # Connecting file/Build menu trigger to function
        self.actionBuild.triggered.connect(lambda: self.BuildIt())
        
    def buildIt(self):
        inputbase = self.InputEdit.text()
        outputbase = self.OutputEdit.text()
        finaldir = self.TitleEdit.text()
        self.buildPlainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Creating final folder in output base folder...")
        os.makedirs(outputbase + "\\" + reldir, 777, True)
        sleep(5) # Sleeping for 5 seconds to see realtime if folder is created before text appears in PlainTextEdit
        self.buildPlainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Archiving files, please wait.")
        self.makerars(inputbase, outputbase, reldir)
    
    def makerars(self, inputbase, outputbase, finaldir):
        subprocess.run(
            [
                self.rarexe,
                "a",
                "-m0",
                "-ep",
                "--",
                str(os.path.join(outputbase, finaldir, finaldir.lower() + ".rar")),
                str(inputbase)
            ]
        )
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing about the order of execution here?

Comment: I suspect the lines are executed in order, but you aren't seeing the *effect* of `appendPlainText` until later, due to buffering or screen updates or something.

Comment: @chepner That actually sounds reasonable, yeah. The GUI is called with what seems to be the default:
`app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()`

Is there anything I can do to see the effects of the `appendPlainText` in realtime?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Updated question with new code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654327/pyqt-force-update-textedit-before-calling-other-function) and I was bad at googling.

This was solved by doing `self.plainTextEdit.repaint()` directly after each `appendPlainText` to repaint inside the GUI loop:

```
self.buildPlainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Creating final folder in output base folder...")
self.buildPlainTextEdit.repaint()
```